# ArrayController's CoreData selection binding not refreshed across multiple NIB files

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I've a hard time getting my Cocoa application to work as expected. It consists of a toolbar in the ***main.nib*** and a custom view in a ***details.nib*** file. Now I want the user to select an entry in a NSPopupButton in the toolbar and the content of the custom view should be changed accordingly.

To achive this I've added an ArrayController to my ***main.nib***, showing the following configuration:

[image: Attributes Inspector for Array Controller]
[image: Managed Object Context Configuration]

Furthermore the Managed Object Context is bound to the Model Key Path ***delegate.managedObjectContext*** (it is no document based application).

With this configuration the NSPopupButton works just fine and if I add a Label to the toolbar (also in the main.nib) and bind it's value to the selection (Controller Key), name (Key Value Path) the content is refreshed whenever I change the selection.

The Bindings of the NSPopupButton look like shown in the following screenshot:
[image: NSPupupButton Bindings]

So in my ***details.nib*** I tried the following to achieve the same effect. I've added an ArrayController, whichs Managed Object Context is also bound to the Model Key Path ***delegate.managedObjectContext***. Also the configuration is exactly the same as shown in the above pictures. I've then added a label and bound it's value to the selection (Controller Key), name (Key Value Path) of this ArrayController.

[image: Label Bindings]

The problem is that the Label only displays the the initial selection after the application did launched correctly. Afterwards, when I change the selection of my NSPopupButton, the label does not change accordingly.

[image]

What are my options to get the ArrayController working accross multiple NIB files?

BTW: I've tried to follow [this blog post](http://appledoc.gentlebytes.com/blog/2009/09/02/coredata-bindings-multiple-nibs/) to get it working but it seems I'm missing something here.

**Update:**
If I replace the Label in the ***details.nib*** by a NSTextField and change the text of it, the changes are reflected in the related NSPopupButton entry. So I guess I made something right, but the main problem remains: I can only edit the entry which was loaded during application startup. Switching to another NSPopupButton entry does not change the text in the NSTextField.

**Update 2:**
I've created a small sample project with exactly the same configuration and uploaded it on **[GitHub](https://github.com/Restage/ACBindingExample)**. So feel free to check it out or create a pull request with a solution approach.

Comment: The AC in main.nib appears to be bound to the selection of the popup.   The AC in details.nib doesn't.   You have a label in details.nib which is bound to the selection of the AC in details.nib, but you have said what the selection of the AC in details.nib is bound to.  Popup and AC selection bindings aren't necessarily the same type... ie. id vs. indexSet.

Comment: @stevesliva I'm not exactly sure what you mean. To be a little bit more clear about my bindings, I've added some more screenshoots.
With this configuration I assumed that two different ArrayController bound to the same ManagedObjectContext would share the same information and if one of them changes, the changes are reflected in the other one as well (because it is bound to the same MOC). But the AC in the details.nib does not seem to be updated when the selection of the AC in the main.nib changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're missing the fact that, when you create the second array controller on the Details.xib it has no relation to the array controller on the MainMenu.xib. They are two separate instances.

When you change the selection on the PopUp the only array controller affected is the one on MainMenu.xib.

You have several options here:

1. When you create your DetailViewController pass a reference to the array controller on the Controller and bind to that (don't create a new one on the details.xib)
2. Just use simple KVO to observe the selection on Controller, and programatically change your label value.
3. Just use simple KVO to observe the selection on Controller and update the array controller on the DetailsViewController to keep them in sync.
4. your solution here...

As long as you understand what's going on I'm sure you'll find the best solution to your original problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right - because I assumed the selection is related to the MOC and not to the AC it can not work the way I implemented it. The first approach sounds like the best solution, but I will try all three in my example project and accept the answer if I get at least one working and no better answer is posted. ;)

Comment: The first option was exactly what I need and it works like charme. Thanks pfandrade, the bounty is well deserved. For anybody interessted in this, I will update my github repository with the working solution over the weekend.